# Notepad2 or Notepad++ and why?

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, notepad2

Why should I choose one over the other, or should I go another way?

Comment: Voting to close this, for there are numerous posts on editors (here, as well as on SO), and this is becoming just one more ...

Comment: Sure, there are similar questions, but this is my specific question.

Comment: your question can be divided into two parts. a) you're asking why should YOU choose one over the other; which is highly subjective, and not really answerable either way (btw, how should someone else know why you should choose something?! if only you've stated some requirements, but like this, no ...) and b) you're asking for a list of editors, which has been covered before so many times ...

Comment: Notepad++ has more features, but Notepad2 is cleaner, faster and can work very well with files much larger than memory. (Notepad++ can't edit a 100GB file)

Answer (score 14):

I've used them both, and Notepad++ is head and shoulders above Notepad2. It's not even a contest.

Comment: Indeed, notepad++ ftw. :)

Comment: Yeah, it is not even a content.

Comment: notepad++ FTW, I wrote a custom syntax highlighter and autocomplete feature for a small DSL in about 2 hours, can you do that in Notepad2?

Answer (score 7):

At a glance, [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) seems a little more feature rich to me. They're both based on the same framework, Scintilla.

But like Chris says, they're both free. Try both.

Also, feel free to use [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) or [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Of course you could always use [butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/) like *real programmers*

Comment: +1 for vim. I only use vim on my *nix boxes

Comment: Exactly, REAL PROGRAMMERS use butterflies!

Answer (score 4):

I prefer Notepad2 because of its lightweightness -- and because it has a nicer interface :) For serious editing, `vim`.

Answer (score 1):

They're both freeware or open source so why don't you download and install them both and try them out to see which one you like the best.

I'm using Notepad++ myself, but that's purely because someone recommended it to me. If they'd recommended Notepad2 then I'd probably be using that.

Comment: Actually, Notepad++ is open source software, not freeware.

Comment: @oKtosiTe - updated, but in this context "open source" is effectively equivalent to "freeware".

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking. It's why I use N++. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Try **[PSPad](http://www.pspad.com/en/)**, too. It's the best lightweight Windows editor I've found yet - lots of great features including USB drive compatibility, favorite directories/projects, plugins, and live FTP editing, to name a few.

Comment: I have used PsPad for YEARS. I like it so much that I have even donated. It is definitely my go-to text editor. However, there are times that I have found N++ more capable.  Just my tuppence.

Answer (score 0):

You should not let anyone to decide which one you should use. You should 
decide which one you want to use, yourself. Try both, for a day, a week - whatever you feel is a good amount of time to determent what kind of editor it is. Then try the other one, and then you'll know which one is right for you!

Also, may I ask why you only seem to consider these two? If you are looking for power in your editor, try [Vim](http://vim.org) or [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), while their learning curve is indeed more steep, I can almost guarantee you it'll be worth it in the long run in terms of productivity, and flexibility. (You can use these editors almost everywhere!)

A friend of mine is very happy with [Sublimetext](http://www.sublimetext.com/), which is also a Windows editor, try it as well in your little personal test.